# took a componet from codpen html , css converted it inot react componet it is working fine as expected in online react playground

Tags: reactjs, codepen

took a componet from codpen html , css converted it inot react componet it is working fine as expected in online react playground but not working properyl in vscode please suggest what mistake i am making
the image yellow overlpaiing with the tesxt when run in vscode but when run in online playground its working absolutely fine

```
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
  }
.container{
    max-width: 540px;
}
  
  .timeline:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 40px;
    width: 2px;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #e9ecef;
  }
  
  .timeline > li {
  
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    
  }
  
  .timeline > li:after,
  .timeline > li:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
  }
  
  .timeline > li:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel:before {
    right: auto;
    left: -15px;
    border-right-width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel:after {
    right: auto;
    left: -14px;
    border-right-width: 14px;
    border-left-width: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline > li .timeline-image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 7px solid #e9ecef;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #ffc800;
  }
  
  .timeline > li .timeline-image h4,
  .timeline > li .timeline-image .h4 {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
    right: auto;
    left: -15px;
    border-right-width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
    right: auto;
    left: -14px;
    border-right-width: 14px;
    border-left-width: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline > li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline .timeline-heading h4,
  .timeline .timeline-heading .h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  .timeline .timeline-heading h4.subheading,
  .timeline .timeline-heading .subheading.h4 {
    text-transform: none;
  }
  
  .timeline .timeline-body > ul,
  .timeline .timeline-body > p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .page-section {
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 6rem 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .page-section h2.section-heading,
  .page-section .section-heading.h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  
  .page-section h3.section-subheading,
  .page-section .section-subheading.h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .timeline:before {
      left: 50%;
    }
  
    .timeline > li {
      min-height: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
      float: left;
      width: 41%;
      padding: 0 20px 20px 30px;
      text-align: right;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image {
      left: 50%;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-left: -50px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image h4,
    .timeline > li .timeline-image .h4 {
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 18px;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
      float: right;
      padding: 0 30px 20px 20px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .timeline > li {
      min-height: 150px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
      padding: 0 20px 20px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: -75px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image h4,
    .timeline > li .timeline-image .h4 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 26px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
      padding: 0 20px 20px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .timeline > li {
      min-height: 170px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
      padding: 0 20px 20px 100px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image {
      width: 170px;
      height: 170px;
      margin-left: -85px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li .timeline-image h4,
    .timeline > li .timeline-image .h4 {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
  
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
      padding: 0 100px 20px 20px;
    }
  }
  
  .page-section {
    padding: 6rem 0;
  }
  
  .page-section h2.section-heading,
  .page-section .section-heading.h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  
  .page-section h3.section-subheading,
  .page-section .section-subheading.h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  
  .text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  .text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
  }
  
  .text-muted {
    --bs-text-opacity: 1;
    color: #6c757d !important;
  }
  
  p {
    line-height: 1.75;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .container-xxl,
    .container-xl,
    .container-lg,
    .container-md,
    .container-sm,
    .container {
      max-width: 1320px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-xl,
    .container-lg,
    .container-md,
    .container-sm,
    .container {
      max-width: 1140px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-lg,
    .container-md,
    .container-sm,
    .container {
      max-width: 960px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-md,
    .container-sm,
    .container {
      max-width: 720px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container-sm,
    .container {
      max-width: 540px;
    }
  }
  
  .container,
  .container-fluid,
  .container-xxl,
  .container-xl,
  .container-lg,
  .container-md,
  .container-sm {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x, 0.75rem);
    padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x, 0.75rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Fade from "react-reveal";

import styles from "./AboutContent.module.css";
import "./AboutContent.module.css"
import "./AboutContentStyles.css"

const AboutContent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="maincontainer">
    <section className="page-section" id="about">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="text-center">
        <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">About</h2>
        <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <ul className="timeline">
        <li>
          <div className="timeline-image"><img className="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/1.jpg" alt="..." /></div>
          <div className="timeline-panel">
            <div className="timeline-heading">
              <h4>2009-2011</h4>
              <h4 className="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="timeline-body">
              <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="timeline-inverted">
          <div className="timeline-image"><img className="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/2.jpg" alt="..." /></div>
          <div className="timeline-panel">
            <div className="timeline-heading">
              <h4>March 2011</h4>
              <h4 className="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="timeline-body">
              <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="timeline-image"><img className="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/3.jpg" alt="..." /></div>
          <div className="timeline-panel">
            <div className="timeline-heading">
              <h4>December 2015</h4>
              <h4 className="subheading">Transition to Full Service</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="timeline-body">
              <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="timeline-inverted">
          <div className="timeline-image"><img className="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/4.jpg" alt="..." /></div>
          <div className="timeline-panel">
            <div className="timeline-heading">
              <h4>July 2020</h4>
              <h4 className="subheading">Phase Two Expansion</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="timeline-body">
              <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="timeline-inverted">
          <div className="timeline-image">
            <h4>
              Be Part
              <br />
              Of Our
              <br />
              Story!
            </h4>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
  );
};

export default AboutContent;
```

Comment: Please try to spell the word correctly (or use a spell checker) and separate your sentences with a `.`, so it's easier to understand your question.